# How to wrap a single string literal across multiple lines?

Tags: string

Is it possible to write a single line for an Elisp string:

```
"hello world"
```

As:

```
"hello
world"
```

Without inserting a newline character? (wrapping a string literal).

I read that adding a tilde at the end of the line does this in some lisp's, but its not working for me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can use a *literal* string that does not include the newline, so that the newline shows only for your code.

Use `\` to escape the newline, so that it is not included in the string:

```el
(setq foo "hello \
world")

C-h v foo

"hello world"
```

One place where this is often used is in a doc string, where the literal string uses `\\<...>` or `\\[...]` constructs that make the doc string look long in the source code.  When rendered as part of the help output the result might show a short key sequence, so you use `\` to chop the literal string in the code but keep it all on one line in the help output.

For example, this doc-string sentence is all on one line, which appears as `You can use this command only from the minibuffer (‘C-%’).` in the help output. But in the source code does not appear as a single, long line - there is a newline after the `\`.

```el
"...
 You can use this command only from the minibuffer (`\\<minibuffer-local-completion-map>\
 \\[icicle-candidate-set-swap]')."
```

Answer (score 7):

Edit, it seems multi-line literals *are* supported, keeping answer since it may be useful still.

You can however use `concat`. eg:

```elisp
(concat "hello"
 "world")
```

Answer (score 1):

have you considered to use `define-skeleton` to insert predfined bloc of texts and more ?
[Emacs Skeleton](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SkeletonMode)